# how disable DST manually in php?

Tags: php, xampp

php via xampp installed on windows server 2008, is there any way(setting, method, functionality, class & etc) to disbale DST (Daylight Saving Time) manually in php/xampp?

Comment: you want to change the timezone ?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` is one option

Comment: i want disable dst for timezone have dst like Asia/Tehran

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php.ini disable daylight saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249673/php-ini-disable-daylight-saving)

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'GMT' or 'Zulu' or 'UTC' with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function,

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Take a look at the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), specifically the [Others](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) section