# php.ini disable daylight saving

Tags: php, timezone, dst, php-ini

Our country stopped daylight saving. Now the time is 20:16
But on PHP the time is 21:16.
Is there any way to disable daylight saving?
My code is:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Can you change your timezone in php.ini?

Comment: yes, but changing to another country's timezone is not good for me. I am living in Baku. And I want to use Baku's real time.

Comment: You could create a new, custom timezone file. Or I bet somebody has already created one. My PHP server is running on a custom timezone that I created myself. Would that work for you?

Comment: How can I do it? Do you know how to update php timezone tables?

Comment: On Linux, I put my new timezone in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, and then set `date.timezone = America/Oklahoma_City_mean_solar_time` under the `[Date]` section in php.ini. I found a website on creating timezone files somewhere. I could try to find it again. That would work if you’re on Linux.

Comment: If that’s the sort of thing you’re looking for, I could write an answer instead of crowding everything into comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2016 change for Azerbaijan is correctly reflected in [the time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) for the `Asia/Baku` time zone as of [release 2016c](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2016-March/000037.html).

PHP gets its time zone information from the [timezonedb PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).  The 2016c tz data, inclusive of the Azerbaijan change, is in timezonedb version 2016.3.

An embedded copy of this is included with each release of PHP, but occasionally there is a need to install it manually, because the releases are not necessarily aligned.  In this case, the latest version of PHP was released on March 3rd, and the version of timezonedb you need was released on March 24th.

[There's a good article here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/correct-php-timezone/) describing how exactly to install the timezonedb PECL package.  After you install the latest version, you should see your code display the correct time.

Also, recognize that the Azerbaijan government only announced the change [on March 17th](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/no-dst-azerbaijan.html), leaving very little time for implementation changes.  Whenever governments provide short notice, situations like yours are bound to arise.  If at all possible, please give feedback to your government to provide more lead time if any other changes are to occur in the future.

Comment: I come here to update my answer... but I see that there is already the perfect answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me: Brazil stopped observing daylight saving time in the year 2019 and as a result, my Xampp installation started showing the wrong time in the summer.

The problem was fixed changing the timezone in **php.ini** file to a UTC-3 region where DST has never been observed (America/Paramaribo) or to a UTC-3 region where DST had not been observed before PHP 5.6 was released (America/Bahia).

That was the only possible solution for me, as the Windows DLL of [timezonedb PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb), referred by Matt Johnson-Pint, was simply incompatible with my Xampp version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, As a fast solution, I've just set the server clock As showing the currect time while daylight saving option is ON like nothing has changed in compare to last year and no file update etc. was done!

Answer (score 0):

You can Customize this optin with this method in CentOS

```
pecl install timezonedb
```

And You should add this line to php.ini

```
extension=timezonedb
```

Finally Restart httpd And PHP services

Comment: this maybe works for linux but what is the solution for windows